# Склонение фамилии Кеввай

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение-фамилий

Скажите, пожалуйста, склоняется ли фамилия *Кеввай*?

Answer (score 1):

Если относится к женщине, то не склоняется. Если относится к мужчине, то склоняется по образцу склонения существительных мужского-среднего рода (в школе - II склонение): Кеввай, Кеввая, Кевваю, Кеввая, Кевваем, Кеввае.